# Integration between Smooch (Sunshine conversations) iOS SDK and Zendesk

Tags: ios, zendesk, smooch

I am following [this guide](https://docs.smooch.io/guide/native-ios-sdk/#installation) to install Zendesk's Sunshine Conversaitons (Smooch) SDK on my iOS app.

I created an integration from the "Conversations integrations" section of Zendesk Admin center. From the integration created I took the integration ID and used it to initialise the iOS Sunshine SDK. The initialisation is failing with this error:"App not found: Provided integration id is invalid"

Any hint of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

With the Sunshine Conversations SDK for iOS, you should follow [this section of the doc](https://docs.smooch.io/guide/native-ios-sdk/#initialize-sunshine-conversations-in-your-app) to create an iOS integration;

When managing your Sunshine Conversations app via the Admin Centre, you'll need to follow the steps to do this using the API:

> It is also possible to create an iOS SDK integration (using type:"ios") through the API, as well as view existing ones as part of an API call to list integrations.

Alternatively, when creating iOS integrations directly in the Admin Centre directly, it would work with the Zendesk Messaging SDK for iOS, so you should refer to the Zendesk docs for more on working with that SDK.

###### Where you (and others) got mixed-up

`Conversations Integrations` are business-facing integrations, typically referred to as `webhooks`; In the docs these are referred to as `custom integrations`, and can be created using the `/integrations` endpoint with `type:custom`.

Customer-facing integrations (or channels) are also created using the `/integrations` endpoint, but with the `type` matching the channel name (e.g.: `whatsapp`, `telegram`, `twilio`, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. A member of the Zendesk team explained that the project was not setup for Smooch yet and helped me to finally make it work. I just couldn't do it by myself, I needed action on Zendesk's side